# Format a string in C# (not number or date) to a given pattern

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Is there something like `string.format` for formatting strings where I can pass a the goal pattern. `string.format` seems to be only for formatting numbers and patterns and inserting values inside a given position. Is there a general solution to formatting strings after a given pattern than programming it out myself?

I want to give the goal pattern and an input string and get out the string in the pattern I’ve provided.

I can give some examples.

```
Input               Output           Input pattern (idea)
---------------------------------------------------------
123.456.001         00123.456.001    00000.000.###
D1234567            D-123-4567       D-000-#### (where D is literal)
```

So, my question is: Is there a way to format a `string` to a given pattern like there is for number and dates?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide at least 6 sample inputs and the expected result for each of those inputs.

Comment: @mjwills ok I‘m gonna try to come up with some. I unfortunately don‘t know what expects me in the future. I fear that I will get 6 different solutions for these 6 cases and not a general solution though.

Comment: _"I don‘t know which kind of formats expect me in the future …  I want to save this formatting pattern to the database and just apply it to any string I get from somewhere else"_ - don't try and write a processing framework before you know what it needs to do. Handle each case as it comes in the simplest and clearest way you can, and once you have done a few you can evaluate the benefits of centralising the processing.

Comment: Showing 6 cases is the only way to work out what a general solution might look like.  How else can we find the pattern in your requirements?

Comment: @khargoosh I was hoping for a framework method that I missed or something like that. There is a method for formatting date and numbers so there might be one for formatting strings. If that‘s not the case I can already close the question.

Comment: I’ve edited the question. Hopefully it is clear now what I want. A simple no as an answer is acceptable. I guessed it doesn‘t exist.
@mjwills " A framework method that handles requirements that you aren't clear about?" I am clear about input and output of the method, just not which formats I‘m expecting.

Comment: Ok, I see now that this was a totally useless question and I need to solve the problem otherwise. Thanks for all comments.

Comment: I think it is a valid question, a couple of more examples wouldn't have hurt. I think this is a job for IFormattable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider making customer formatter classes for each of the different formats you require. There is a very simple example below with no error handling etc...

```
// custom formatter class
public class FormatD : IFormattable
{
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return format[0] + "-" + format.Substring(1,3) + "-" + format.Substring(4);
    }
}
```

To call:

```
 var input = "D1234567";
 var ouput = String.Format("{0:" + input + "}", new FormatD());
```

Comment: I think this suits my need the best. Accepting this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible with `String.Format()`. You would need to dissect the different parts of your pattern using regular expressions or similar.

For your example a solution could be

```
public string ReplacePattern(string input)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(input, @"([A-Z])(\d{3})(\d{4})");
    if(match.Groups.Count == 4) // The first group is always the input
    {
        return String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", match.Groups.Skip(1).Take(3).ToArray());
    }
    return "";
}
```

Edit: I forgot: of course you can always use regular expression replacements:

```
public string ReplacePattern(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"([A-Z])(\d{3})(\d{4})", "$1-$2-$3");
}
```